# A property for functions that belong to the fractional Sobolev space $W^{s,p}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Let $p\geq1$ and $s\in(0,1)$. We define the fractional Sobolev space as the space of functions $f\in L^{p}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ such that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|\frac{f\left(x\right)-f\left(y\right)}{x-y}\right|^{p}\frac{1}{\left|x-y\right|^{1+(s-1)p}}dxdy<+\infty.\tag{1}$$ My question is about the “regularity” of $f$ that can be deduced from $(1)$. In particular, we know that $W^{1,p}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)\subset W^{s,p}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$, and so $f$ could not be weakly differentiable, but it seems to me that some type of “Lipschitz continuity-type” property must holds. I think this because $(1)$ is bigger than $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\left|z\right|<1}\left|\frac{f\left(y+z\right)-f\left(y\right)}{z}\right|^{p}\frac{1}{\left|z\right|^{1+(s-1)p}}dzdy$$ and so some type of regularity must holds for keeping this integral convergent. Maybe I'm completely wrong since I am not able to find articles or books that consider this aspect.

My question is: Am I wrong? What kind of “regularity” we can deduce about a function $f\in W^{s,p}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$?

Comment: What do you mean "what kind of regularity" ? The finiteness of this integral is already a "kind of regularity" of order $s$. By Sobolev embeddings, it implies also that you are in $L^{p^*}$ with $p^*> p$, or in some Hölder space if $s>1/p$, and then in all the triangle between $L^{p^*}$, $L^p$ and $W^{s,p}$ as in this drawing https://laurent-lafleche.perso.math.cnrs.fr/images/GagNir.svg

Comment: @LL3.14 I wrote what I mean in the question: since integral $(1)$ is convergent, can we deduce some kind of “Lipschitz continuity-type” regularity? I also wrote why I'm thinking about this type of property, just see the second double integral. I explain better my, probably wrong, ideas: I suspect that if $f$ is not Lipschitz continuous in a set $E$ with $\mu(E)>0$, then the double integral does not converge.

Comment: No, none of the spaces with $s<1$ is embedded in $W^{1,\infty}$ that is the space of lipschitz functions, hence you can find counterexamples